# How to write object id reference of mongoose using Sequelize for MySql in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I am trying to write the category model for MySQL using Sequelize taking reference from this code of mongoose model in node(shared below) . I have gone through some articles but going through some confusion. Please help.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    createdBy: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
  },
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema);
```

Here I've tried my code in using Sequelize for MySql but got stuck in createdBy block. Need Help!!!

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Category = sequelize.define("categories", {
        name:{
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
        },
      createdBy:{
      
      }
    });
  
    return Category;
  };
```

Comment: Pls share the code you are referring to in your question along with any error messages you receive.

Answer (score 0):

The `createdBy` value from Mongo will be an ObjectID, which you can save as a string in MySQL, so use a `DataTypes.STRING` type in the definition, then set it on insert/update/etc from your Mongo lookup. The `Sequelize` variable in your example should be `DataTypes` as well.

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Category = sequelize.define('categories', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    createdBy: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      // any other settings
    },
  });

  return Category;
};
```

```js
// get the value from mongoose
const createdBy = ...;

// set it on the create for your model to insert.
await Category.create({
  name: 'Some Name',
  createdBy,
});
```